# How to implement a persisting ConcurrentQueue?

Tags: c#, queue

I have a simple message queue type implementation which uses the ConcurrentQueue to queue messages. I need to persist this in case of a crash but cannot seem to find a good persistent queue implementation. Any suggestions?

Comment: You have to provide a bit of information: application, platform, persistance-type (database, filesystem, network)?

Comment: Or use something like MSMQ rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: It's pretty much a simple c# app that receives and sends the messages. I didn't want to use msmq since all I need is crash recovery and msmq seems very bloated.

Comment: As for persistence type I think file it probably the best considering it's just for crash-recovery, but db is ok too I guess.

Comment: Just for completion sake, the solution I opted for was just to binary serialize my queue. My process was not very dependant on speed so this works quite well for me, kept the code base small and was not complex to understand.

Comment: @MladenMihajlovic maybe you could post your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I've done in the past is use a real low-tech solution. Every time an item was added to or removed from the queue, I wrote an entry to a file. The file started out empty. Then I had:

```
add item 1
add item 2
remove item 1
add item 3
remove item 2
remove item 3
add item 4
...
```

For crash recovery, I opened the file and read it from the top, adding and removing things until I got to the end of the file.

When the program shut down normally, it would write a new file with "add" records representing the current state of the queue. The next time the program started, it load the file to initialize the queue.

This worked well for my application, but the queue wasn't exactly huge volume. I modified it a bit so that it would periodically output the full queue contents and destroy any history. The primary reason for that was to reduce the amount of disk space used and speed loading time if it crashed.

Another possibility is to use a circular queue on disk, although that can be painful. Unless you can set a maximum queue size and the records are a fixed length (or you know a maximum length), managing the file becomes incredibly complicated. At that point, a simple database implementation is much better.

It's really too bad that file systems don't have a "truncate file at front" function. Because if they did then implementing a persistent queue would be trivial.

Comment: Thanks for you help, Jim. The file add/remove item idea is actually a great one. My queue is not really high volume (although it could become high volume in the future), but there will always be down-time so I could maybe use that as a "maintenance period" to clear the file out.